# PHP: Maximum amount of uploadable files, $_FILES maxed out at 25 entries

Tags: nginx, php

I have a rather old page, where a lot of file upload input fields reside. The problem is, only the first 25 upload field's data gets populated after the post.

I'm using nginx+php5.3-fpm

`max_file_uploads` is set to 200, so that can't be the problem. There are also a lot of other input fields besides the file inputs, and they arrive just fine, all of them.

Any ideas, where should I look?

Comment: Are you getting any particular error message or is the page just hanging?

Comment: Have you run a `phpinfo();` to check the 200 value is sticking (e.g. you edited a php.ini which the webserver ignores)?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I GOT IT! It was suhosin's own restriction in effect:

suhosin.upload.max_uploads is set to 25